# Has any scholar/mufti responded to Answering Islam's webpage "The Dilemma of Jihad Doctrine"?

Tags: jihad

Jihad in Islam has been widely misinterpreted. I tired of answering my fellow friends and colleagues on what is right and what is wrong. They take out quranic verses out of context and asks me "How can I say Islam is a religion of peace?". I am not a learned scholar, but in most cases I can guide them properly. Recently one of my friends, showed me this

- Mutee'a Al Fadi, *The Dilemma of Jihad Doctrine: The Myth of Quranic Warnings vs. Violence Commands* (URL below*):

It is widely used by haters of Islam to broadcast that Islam supports terrorism.

This is a long list. Has any scholar/mufti responded to these misinterpreted verses? If yes, please share.

- www.answering-islam.org/Quran/Themes/jihad_passages.html

Comment: Maybe helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28682/how-do-non-violent-muslims-explain-the-violent-verses-of-the-koran

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes it does answer some part of it. If you check the link mentioned in the question, you will see 164 verses taken out of context. Since this is very wide spread, I was hoping that some scholar or mufti has taken the time out to give an answer to this idiocy. If there has been some effort already done, then I could forward the same material. That should silence my protagonist friends.

Answer (score -3):

There are answers to all such misinterpretations, in various articles, lectures, books, sites, etc. About such verses, most are referring to defence and/or retaliation once attacked by non-believers, rather than initiate a fight. Also, as opposed to these 164 verses, there are 100's of verses on peace, humility, helping, etc which are not paid heed to. As you have felt yourself, haters are not willing/accepting to learn from such clarifications.